# Unregistered users tend to post "answers" to own questions that are not answers

Tags: discussion

An unregistered user just [asked a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8264/1235) and soon after that posted an "answer" that should have been a comment. Usually, the system asks you quite clearly if you're really sure that you want to answer your own question. Here, the mechanism doesn't work as the user created a new (unregistered) account for the "answer". I've got two questions:

1. Is it of any use to leave comments to the "answer" in this case? Unregistered users can't delete their answers anyway.
2. Is there any way to make it harder for unregistered users to do this?

In order to show that this is not a singular occurence, [here are](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7105/1235) [a few](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7843/1235) [more](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7977/1235) [examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5582/1235).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually leave a comment pointing out that they should register, and then ask the mods to do a merge. It is a bit frustrating, I agree. (I've done some mod work on the examples, as these might otherwise get forgotten. Non-answers shouldn't really be left as 'answers' for too long, I think.)

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. So in the future I know what I'll do: Flag for moderator attention if comments don't help.